# Grails : Error generating web.xml file

Tags: grails, stack-trace, web.xml

I have upgraded my Grails project from version 2.1.2 to 2.2.3. Before the upgrade, the project worked flawlessly. However, I am not able to run the project now. I get a strange error :

```
| Compiling 143 source files.....
| Error Error generating web.xml file (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

and the compilation stops.

I thought that the "--stacktrace" option would provide some useful information. However, I am not able to decipher the error.

Error here > http://pastebin.com/zwR4YzXS

Googling / searching this problem did not help. I hope I am not the only one, who is getting this error.

Thank you for your advices !

Some useful info :

```
Grails 2.2.3

Java version :
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 x64
```

Comment: you've tried `grails clean` yeah?

Comment: I am dumbass...deleting the content of the target folder solved the problem...thank you much !!!

Comment: I noticed that error sometimes too. I needed to explicit add the webxml plugin dependency.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Faced the same issue while working with grails 2.3.2. Actually, I added and then removed  clojure plugin. Right after got such problem.

`$ grails clean` just worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem i was facing i used the below command :

grails clean

grails refresh-dependencies

and that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Intellij the problem is that:
the reason for this is that IDEA adds classpath by default on creating integration test run configuration. So if you run tests you might cause that error

Open Run → Edit Configurations... (or press Alt-Shift-F10)
Select your configuration that fails
Uncheck Add --classpath checkbox
You are done! Run.